# Data Studio doesn't request all the fields to my Community Connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm making a Community Connector with the following fields, among others: Age, gender and impressions.

When I try to do a bar chart with Impressions as a metric, Age as a dimension and Gender as a breakdown dimension (or Gender and Age, inverted) I get the following error:

```
User Configuration Error

This data source was improperly configured.

Invalid argument type.

Error ID: b44d6288
```

Debugging, I found the problem is that it isn't making a single request to getData() including the three fields (which, when processed, would make the right call to the API and get the right data). Instead it only requests the pair dimension-metric on one request and sometimes also breakdown dimension-metric on others (and, sometimes, dimension-metric with filter info), which gives it a "broken" data which it apparently can't make sense of. As the request to my getData() only includes two fields, I return two fields per row. Info about the third one can't be found nowhere, especially on the request parameter, as far as I can see.

This behavior appeared somewhere along the development of the connector -- at some points this exact combination worked normal.

As this behavior doesn't include code it's really scaring me. Any idea would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Francisco, did you find any solution to that? Experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: It is hard to help without some code. However, your getData function need to be consistent to what is requested. Data Studio will decide how to use according to visual configuration. If it requires a specific parameter to work properly, it is badly written.